# Vue load component in collapsible accordion component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-4, components

I'm working on a page that has several accordion expandable drop-downs. It looks something like this:
[image]

Each step, when expanded, will render a different component. For example, if "Step 1" was expanded, it would load the `StepOne.vue` component.

For the actual Accordion code, I have created a component here:

**Accordion.vue** (template)

```
<template>
<div id="accordion">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" :id="givenId">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          {{stepStr}} // step 1,2,3 -etc
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" :aria-labelledby="givenId" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
      // I want to load a dynamic component here.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</template>
```

My problem is, I'm not sure how to make each accordion step load a different component, without copy pasting the entire accordion html code for each step.

Ideally, I want it to look something like this:

**Display.vue**

```
<template>
  // Step 1
  <accordion :id="step-1" :stepStr="'Step 1'">
      <Step-One></Step-One>
  </accordion>

  // Step 2
  <accordion :id="step-2" :stepStr="'Step 2'">
      <Step-Two></Step-Two>
  </accordion>

  // Step 3
  <accordion :id="step-3" :stepStr="'Step 3'">
      <Step-Three></Step-Three>
  </accordion>
</template>
```

But this is an invalid approach, or at least, I don't know how to make it work. I also looked into passing the component, as a prop, to be rendered in the accordion. But that does not seem to be a valid solution, either.

How can I pass a component to my child Accordion component, so that it can render each "step" component, correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use slot

```
<slot></slot>
```

in your accordion component, where you wish to display the code in between your accordion tags.

```
 <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" :aria-labelledby="givenId" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
          <slot></slot> // I want to load a dynamic component here.
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I looked into slots when I was trying to figure this out. Can you pass an entire component via a slot? I remember reading you could only pass template code. But I could be mistaken. Also, in your example, how would the slot know which component to load?

Comment: it basically should try to load the component you place in between your accordians, as there is only one slot it does not need a name, if you want to name the slot you can so that you explicitly have different formats of slots for different kinds of components you have

Comment: Interesting, so the code in my Display.vue is actually valid, as in, that's how I would pass a slot? I will try this out, and report back afterwards. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: i would definitely like a feed back... hope that works :)